# Show only a certain number of contacts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I have developed a program that shows a list of contacts from my phone book. 
For this I use the following code:

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'",
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
           Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id)); 
            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                    null,
                    null);
            if (phones != null) {
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        contactList.add(new Contact(name, phoneNumber, id));
                    }

                phones.close();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(contactList, R.layout.contacts_list_item, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Everything works, and the program displays all contacts from my phone book, but **I want a certain number of contacts to be displayed**. **For example: 
I open the program and load the first 50 contacts from the phone book, after scrolling, the next 50 contacts are loaded to the end of the list. and so on**

Comment: for this you need to implement pull to refresh functionality

Comment: @AbdulWaheed 
How do I limit the number of downloaded contacts at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code that has limit cause. Replace your code with below

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1' ",
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC LIMIT 10");
```

It will get first 10 records. And in pull to refresh implementation, get more records on call back event of pull to refresh. Hope this will help you

Comment: it works, but how do I download the next 10 contacts in OnLoadMoreListener, because I'm getting contacts that have already been downloaded

Comment: you will be required to keep record how many records you have loaded and how many you want and update accordingly

Answer (score -1):

I assume the reason you want this is because loading all contacts is very slow.
The reason it's very slow is because you currently have 1 query per contact, so if a user has 500 contacts, you'll need to run 500 queries.

You can reduce the number of queries to just one, then I assume you won't need the limit thing.

```
String[] projection = { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String name = phones.getString(1);
    String phone = phones.getString(2);
    Long id = phones.getLong(0);

    contactList.add(new Contact(name, phone, id));
}
phones.close();
```

If you want to display only one item per contact, and not per phone, you can change your `contactList` field to be a `HashMap<Long, Contact>` instead of a `List`, and add newly found phones to an existing `Contact` object if it already exists in the Map.

Something like:

```
Contact contact = allContacts.get(id);
if (contact == null) {
    contact = new Contact(name, phone, id);
    allContacts.put(id, contact);
} else {
    contact.addPhone(phone); // you'll need to implement this
}
```